# VBA Enable filtering in cell with List (Data validation)

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to make cell with data validation (list) have menu of filtering like normal table column ?
[Filter menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ6de.png)
vs this :
[List Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syVbq.png)

Comment: No there's no option for that type of filter when using a Data Validation list.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I found other way of handling this. User can pick from list as well as Type part of what he is looking for (by disabling list validation error) and code puts filter on the corresponding hidden column with `*{user_text}*` regex

```
    If target.Address = "$L$3" Then
        If Range("L3").Value = "All" Then
         ActiveSheet.Range("B9:AN" & NumRows).AutoFilter Field:=5
         Exit Sub
        End If
        With ActiveSheet
        Crit = "*" & Range("L3").Value & "*"
            .Range("B9:AN" & NumRows).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Crit
        End With
    End If
```

This is flexible enough so user dont have to browse through 500 positions.